# Infinite sum in a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, and $S$ a regular local analytic $K$-algebra. We may assume $S\simeq K\{z_0,\cdots,z_k\}$, the convergent power series ring.

Given $0\neq f\in \mathfrak m_S$, a pair of matrices $(\phi,\psi)\in S^{n\times n}\times S^{n\times n}$ is called a **matrix factorisation** of $f$, if $\phi\circ\psi=\psi\circ\phi=f\cdot I_{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

A morphism $(\phi_1,\psi_1)\to (\phi_2,\psi_2)$ between matrix factorisations of $f$ is given by a pair $(\alpha,\beta)\in S^{n_2\times n_1}\times S^{n_2\times n_1}$, such that $\alpha\circ\phi_1=\phi_2\circ\beta$, where $n_1$, $n_2$ are the rank of $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, respectively. We write $(\phi_1,\psi_1)\simeq (\phi_2,\psi_2)$ if there exists a morphism $(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are both isomorphisms.

Now I want to show that

> if a matrix factorisation $(\phi,\psi)$ of $f$ satisfies $(\phi,\psi)\simeq (\psi,\phi)$, then there exists another matrix factorisation $(\phi_0,\phi_0)$ of $f$ such that $(\phi,\psi)\simeq (\phi_0,\phi_0)$. Here $\phi,\psi,\phi_0\in S^{n\times n}$ for some positive integer $n$.

In his paper in 1987 on simple singularities, H. Knörrer presented an elegant proof to the result which reads the following:

> We may assume $(\phi,\psi)$ is indecomposable, i.e. can not be written as
> $$(\phi,\psi)\simeq (\begin{pmatrix}\phi_1&0\\0&\phi_2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\psi_1&0\\0&\psi_2\end{pmatrix}).$$
> Let $(\alpha,\beta):(\phi,\psi)\to (\psi,\phi)$ be an isomorphism, then $(\beta\circ\alpha,\alpha\circ\beta)$ is an automorphism of $(\phi,\psi)$. It is known that the quotient of the endomorphism ring $\mathrm{End}(\phi,\psi)$ by its radical is isomorphic to $K$.
> So we may assume
> $$(\beta\circ\alpha,\alpha\circ\beta)=(I_n,I_n)+(\rho_1,\rho_2),\ (\rho_1,\rho_2)\in \mathrm{radEnd}(\phi,\psi).$$
> This implies $\alpha\circ\rho_1=\rho_2\circ\alpha$, $\beta\circ\rho_2=\rho_1\circ\beta$. Now choose (convergent) series for $(1+x)^{-1/2}$ and put
> $$\alpha':=\alpha\circ (I_n+\rho_1)^{-1/2}=(I_n+\rho_2)^{-1/2}\circ\alpha,$$
> and
> $$\beta':=\beta\circ (I_n+\rho_2)^{-1/2}=(I_n+\rho_1)^{-1/2}\circ\beta.$$
> Then $(\alpha',\beta')$ is also a morphism from $(\phi,\psi)$ to $(\psi,\phi)$ and $\alpha'\circ\beta'=\beta'\circ\alpha'=I_n$. Now choose an automorphism $\gamma\in S^{n\times n}$ such that $\gamma^2=\alpha'$, and we let $\phi_0:=\gamma\circ\psi\circ\gamma=\gamma^{-1}\circ\phi\circ\gamma^{-1}$.

However, I have a question regarding this proof:
**What does it mean when we substitute $\rho_1,\rho_2$ into some series?**

Since $\rho:=(\rho_1,\rho_2)$ is a radical element in the endomorphism ring, we certainly need that $(1+\rho)^{-1/2}$ is also a well-defined endomorphism. Naturally I think this endomorphism is defined on each point, so we need a definition for an element $(x+\rho(x))^{-1/2}$, which is an infinite sum. I think this has something to do with the topology we choose so that the series converges, but I am not sure about how to justify this process.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!